# ¿Como darle un rango a una funcion?

Tags: c, dev-c++

¿Tengo una duda como haria para darle un rango el cual no pueda superar dentro de la funcion?.

Por que la consigna  a seguir es la siguiente:

> Crea un código que sume dos números, validando que los mismos estén dentro del rango [1-1.000.000.000]. En caso contrario se deberán mostrar mensajes en pantalla que expliquen el error. El programa debe contar con al menos una función que encapsule el comportamiento deseado.

Esto es lo que puede avanzar del codigo y la verdad no se que faltaria para que en la salida no este mostrando todo el tiempo el 1.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int suma(int a, int b){

     return (a < 1000000 + b < 1000000);
     return (a > 0 + b > 0);
 }

 int main(){

 suma(5, -7);

 printf("El resultado es: %d", suma);

 }
```

Comment: La función "suma" debería de llevar un bloque condicional "if" en donde se evalúe que los numeros estén dentro de ese rango.

Comment: Te da 1 porque estás sumando dos valores de tipo booleano. Verdadero o Falso, 0 o 1.

Answer (score 0):

La resolucion seria de la siguiente forma para el que quiera saber:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int comprobacion(int a, int b){

return (a>0 && a<20) == (b>0 && b<20);
}

int suma(int a, int b){

return a + b;
}

int main(){

int compro=comprobacion (2, 10);
int sumando = suma(2, 10);  
if(compro==1){
    printf("%d es correcto", sumando);
}
else{
    printf("Error");
}   
}
```